# Set UserId for userAccount reply microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework

I am trying to get a users skype  Id. So when the user interacts with my bot, eventually in the future I can contact him again.

When I use skype and get the message from the user first and make:

```
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: activity.From.Name, id: activity.From.Id);
```

I can proceed with sending him a message. 
That message is: the `userAccount.id` which gives me the value I was looking for.

The userAccount.Id is a huge value:
29:1mafWbx... with 66 characters.

When i try to replace in the above code `activity.From.Id` with the 29:1ma.... I am getting a messsage saying Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.

Comment: Can you post the whole code and/or explain more your scenario and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't know if it answer your question, but I prefer to store the whole address of the conversation, so in the future you can reuse it - Look for proactive messaging in [node](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/UniversalBot/#proactive-messaging) or the [C# version](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/templates/proactive/)